# point to polygon distance in postgresql and java

Tags: java, postgresql, polygon, distance, point

I have two vector layers: point layer and polygon layer.
I would like to calculate distance between points and each polygons where the points are not in polygon.
I already have two table for each layer and also I know which points are in which polygon. now I wanna know the distance between those points which are not in the polygon and the polygon.

I am using java and postgresql, what i want to know how to use st-functions to do it.

thanks
Raha

Comment: Did you check the manual for `ST_Distance`?

Comment: With "st-functions" you mean that you are using PostGIS?

Comment: yeah!
I checked st_distance, as I understood, Fisr I should create a ring for Polygon using ST_ExteriorRing then usde st_distance to calculate distance from the ring! Unfortunately, I got an Error!

Comment: select ST_Distance( SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(SELECT geom from osm_art_shops where gid =2) AS ering, select geom from art_shops_flickr where id='5124.00000000');

Comment: this is my query:
ST_Distance(SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS ering from osm_art_shops where gid =2, select geom from art_shops_flickr where id=5124.00000000);

Answer (score 0):

finally, I could calculate distance between point and polygon in PostGIS

in order to calculate distance between point and polygon, first polygon should be converted to an ExteriorRing Usin St_exteriorRing(Geometry), then bu St_distance (geometry, geometry), the distance can be resulted.

this is an example :)

```
     select ST_Distance(    
  (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS ering from osm_art_shops where gid =1),
  (select geom from art_shops_flickr where id=5124)
 );
```